Ant Design select issue ( Showing step icon in select component )
Ant design select issue
I'm encountering an issue with the Ant Design Select component in my React project. Specifically, a step icon is unexpectedly appearing within the Select dropdown, which I can't seem to remove or understand why it’s there.

Documentation Review: I thoroughly reviewed the Ant Design documentation to find any properties or configurations that might control the appearance of icons within the Select component. Unfortunately, I didn't find any relevant information.

CSS Inspection: I inspected the CSS styles to ensure there were no overriding styles or external CSS influencing the Select component. I couldn’t identify any CSS that would introduce the step icon.

Component Isolation: I isolated the Select component in a minimal example to rule out any interference from other parts of the code. The issue persisted even in isolation.

Version Check: Verified the versions of both Ant Design and React to ensure compatibility and checked if the issue might be a bug in the specific versions I’m using.

Community Search: Searched through GitHub issues, Stack Overflow posts, and other forums to see if anyone else has reported a similar problem. Found some related issues but nothing that matched my specific scenario.


I expected the Select component to render a simple dropdown without any additional icons or unexpected elements. The dropdown options should only display the text provided within the Option components, without any step indicators or other icons appearing by default.

Which version of Ant Design library you are using? also which Browser? If possible try putting a sample code in Stackblitz and share it here.

@VishnuSKrish  using   "antd": "^4.16.1", and browser is Google Chrome

Did u checked pseudo elements in Chrome DevTools while inspecting that stepper icon? May be that icon added by some overriding css.

Thank you all for your help. I have received an answer to my question and will be closing this thread.
I just added:
overflow: hidden;

